Estimate the correlation coefficient of a two-dimentional normal distribution $(X,Y)$, given some samples of $(|X|, |Y|)$
I have two random variables $X,Y$, whose joint distribution is a two-dimensional normal distribution, and the expectations of both $X,Y$ are zero. Let $\rho={\rm cov}(X,Y)$ be their correlation coefficient.
Assume I have some unbiased sampling of $|X|$ and $|Y|$, that is, two data sets $\{|x_i|\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{|y_i|\}_{i=1}^N$. I want to get some information of $\rho$. I know getting an unbiased estimation of $\rho$ is impossible since $(X,Y) $ and $(X,-Y)$ will give the same pair $(|X|, |Y|)$, but they have opposite correlation coeffecient. But I still want to get some information of $\rho$. For example, can I get some knowledge of $|\rho|$, like $|\rho| < 0.5$ or $|\rho|>0.5$?

Do you have any information about the variances of $X$ and $Y$, such as them both being $1$, or being equal to each other?

@Henry I have no information of the variances of $X$ and $Y$. Just know they have means 0 and are jointly normal.

I would have guessed that you could do best by looking at $\dfrac{\sum |X_i|, |Y_i|}{\sqrt{\sum |X_j|^2 \sum |Y_k|^2}}$ and consider its distribution conditional on $|\rho|$

I commented that I would have guessed that you could do best by looking at $\dfrac{\sum |X_i|\, |Y_i|}{\sqrt{\sum |X_j|^2 \sum |Y_k|^2}}$ and consider its distribution conditional on $|\rho|$.
Here is a simulation when $N=10^4$ illustrating the relationship:

Unfortunately this may be less useful for much smaller sample sizes. The equivalent simulated chart when $N=10$ shows a more diffuse relationship:

with the second chart produced using R with
abscor <- function(samplesize){
  rho <- runif(1)
  Z <- rnorm(samplesize)
  X <- (rnorm(samplesize)*sqrt(1-rho)+Z*sqrt(rho))
  Y <- (rnorm(samplesize)*sqrt(1-rho)+Z*sqrt(rho))
  c(rho, sum(abs(X)*abs(Y))/sqrt(sum(X^2)*sum(Y^2)))
  }
set.seed(2024)
sims <- replicate(100000, abscor(samplesize=10))
plot(sims[1,], sims[2,], pch=".", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1),
   xlab="|rho|", 
   ylab="sum |X| |Y| / sqrt( sum |X|^2 sum |Y|^2 )" )

